# Get first converted PNG file from GIF in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, gif, mogrify

I'm trying to convert and resize GIF file to PNG file with Command :

```
mogrify.exe -define bmp:format=bmp3 -compress none -resize "300x200>" -antialias -format "png" -units PixelsPerInch -density 72 "img.gif"
```

But it's creating many images with postfix 0 to 31(**img-0.png** to **img-31.png**).

When I use `'-flatten'`, I am getting merge single file but I just wanted first converted file (img-0.png).

Do we have any option for this?

GIF image :
[image]

'-flatten' image : 
[image]

First Image :
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: -antialias will do nothing for your command. -define bmp:format=bmp3 will do nothing for your command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `img.gif[0]` instead of `img.gif` only the first frame will be saved. And it looks like you also don't need the `-define bmp:format=bmp3` because you are saving the file to `png`.